# Electron - how to get MainProcess to initiate the first message by sending the first message to the Renderer

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I have a slider element on my main process's index.html and I'm trying to get value changes from the slider to be sent continuously to a renderer process. Here is a code snippet

```
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = slider.value; 
  /*
     Insert some code that will send slider.value to the 
     renderer process from Main upon every change from the 
     slider.
  */
}
```

Here is the code inside my renderer:

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

 ipc.on('slider-change', (event, message) => {
    console.log(message)
  })
```

Note: I've already tried using `win.WebContents.send()` but that doesn't work since my main win is created inside a function inside another file => main.js. The code for the slider is in a separate js file => ipd-slider.js

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you going to sync slider value between main and renderer?

Comment: If so, you should say like you are rendering the slider element and wanna get live value from this slider at main process.

Comment: May I got your point?

Comment: Yes. The slider is in the main process and I want to send the live value to the renderer. Do you know how I can go about doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by having slider at main process?

Comment: index.html is part of renderer not main

Comment: Well, recommend you to check this first.

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes

Comment: The main process loads my index.html via `win.loadFile('index.html')`

Comment: Ok. To let you understand easier. Let's say main is for managing the renderers. And index.html is one renderer.

Comment: You can set the initial value of the slider by using ipc Communication. So you can send the message from main to renderer to set the slider value.